# Add space before body while printing page

Tags: html, css, media

I want to add some space when I print the document before html body. I tried both margin-top and padding-top in my stylesheet but it has no effect.

How would I add whitespace before the printed content? Any help will be appreciated

```
@media print 
{
    html,body,div,table,tr,td,span
    { 
        padding-top:550px;
        margin-top:550px; 
    }

    .noShow 
    {
        display:none;
    }

    .screenHide
    {
        display:inline;
    } 


}
```

Comment: What exact space do you want to add before body? If you want to go for white-space before the background-color, you'll not accomplish this with CSS.
Background-images could be put down with background-position. 
And the rest is possible with margin-top or padding-top just on body.
So, I can't see a problem with your code from the small part you just added, a jsfiddle example would help further with more of your code. I put up that and it works: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Volker_E/9nBPL/1/show/

Answer (score 0):

Find the relevant section within the HTML document, and enter 
 a bunch of times, and work off process of trial and error.

= break AKA enter (however mark up languages don't understand white space)

So we have to force it.

i.e.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>I need space</title>
<head></head>
<body>


<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /> /* will give you 6 lines worth of space */
I need space before this paragraph!

</body>
</html>
```